# How can I show iPhone simulator's console on Organizer like iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, logging, ios-simulator

The iPhone device console is shown in the Organizer window (shift+command+2), but not the iPhone Simulator.  I want to see the console on the Organizer window, (not Xcode console [shift+command+y]).

How can I show the iPhone simulator's console on organizer like for iPhone device?

Comment: The accepted answer explain how to find the crash reports generated, but the question asked for the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console logs from the Simulator are saved to file and will not show in the organizer window.  You can usually find them here:

```
/Users/ME/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SOMELOGFILE.crash
```

If not there, run this command (from a terminal) to find them:

```
find / -type f -iname "\*.crash"
```

Or, run these 2 (if you have `locate`):

```
updatedb
locate "*.crash"
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question that was asked

Answer (score 5):

You can find messages from the iPhone Simulator with

> tail -f /var/log/system.log

on your OS X machine